# How Do You Mock EntityManger In TypeORM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following code to mock entityManager from my NestJS service, it works to some extent but the issue comes with specifying what the `findOne` should return for different entity.

```
    {
      provide: getEntityManagerToken(),
      useFactory: (connection: Connection) => {
        const entityManager = {
          getRepository: jest.fn(() => {
            return {
              findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}),
              save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(carData),
              createQueryBuilder: jest.fn(() => ({
                select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                leftJoinAndSelect: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                addGroupBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                groupBy: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
                getOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(''),
              })),
            };
          }),
        };
        return entityManager;
      },
    },
```

My Service looks like the below code:

```
export class CarService {
  constructor(
    @InjectEntityManager()
    private readonly entityManager: EntityManager,
  ) {
    this.carRepository = entityManager.getRepository(Car);
    this.modelRepository = entityManager.getRepository(Model);
   }
    
      const car = await this.carRepository.findOne(data.id);

      const model = await this.modelRepository.findOne(data.modelId);
```

How do I mock the findOne result from `this.carRepository` to be different from the findOne result  in `this.modelRepository` considering that they both will be called within the same service.

Comment: I would suggest you *don't* mock it - that's a complex interface that you don't own. Consider having repository facades that wrap the entity managers, then you can mock _those_ out when testing `CarService`. Then have higher-level tests that make sure everything works with the really entity managers.

Comment: you may check my answer on a similar post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67003599/7811556

Answer (score 1):

We have the possibility of using the [EntityManager API](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-manager-api.md) to create transactions with several repositories that can execute a rollback automatically if any of these operations fail, and in the tests we can use the Singleton pattern to define a mock of this entity that allows us to return the same instance of these repositories to test that all these read and write operations have been performed as expected. e.g

```
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let entityManager: EntityManager;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: EntityManager, useValue: createMock<EntityManager>() },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(CatalogsService);
    entityManager = module.get(EntityManager);
  });
  
  it('should call a transaction correctly', async () => {
    const mockEntityManager = {
      save: jest.fn(),
      getCustomRepository: jest.fn((fn) => mockEntityManager[fn] || (mockEntityManager[fn] = createMock<typeof fn>())),
    };
    const spyTransaction = (entityManager.transaction as jest.Mock).mockImplementation((cb) => cb(mockEntityManager));
    const firstRepo: FirstRepository = mockEntityManager.getCustomRepository(SubCatalogRepository);
    const secondRepo: SecondRepository = mockEntityManager.getCustomRepository(SecondRepository);
    await service.saveSomething('MOCK DATA');

    expect(spyTransaction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(firstRepo.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(secondRepo.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockEntityManager.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

As we can see, it's very easy to mock these external services such as the TypeORM EntityManager, etc. using the [createMock](https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/testing#motivation) function, which automatically injects Jest mock functions to replace external implementations on which our code depends, which in a unit test should not matter.

Happy coding! <3

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me and I feel that's simple to read, no external libraries needed, just using Jest.

```
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let entityManager: EntityManager;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
        { provide: EntityManager, useValue: {
          query: jest.fn(),
          // you can mock other functions inside
          // the entity manager object, my case only needed query method
          }
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(MyService);
    entityManager = module.get(EntityManager);
  });

//... rest of your testing

})
```